# How to show user-defined products in cms page?

Tags: magento-1.7

please help me. I am beginner to magento. I have 50 products in 3 categories. I want to show only the product 1, 10,20,25 in magento cms page. how to do, guide me with step by step please.

Answer (score 0):

select cpe.SKU as ProdcutCode,cpev.value as ProductName,ccev.value as  from catalog_product_entity cpe left join catalog_product_entity_varchar cpev on cpev.entity_id = cpe.entity_id left join catalog_category_product ccp on ccp.product_id = cpe.entity_id left join catalog_category_entity_varchar ccev on ccev.entity_id = ccp.category_id

where cpev.attribute_id = 71 and cpev.entity_type_id = 4 and ccev.attribute_id = 41 and ccev.store_id = 0 and ccev.entity_type_id = 3 and cpe.sku =1 or cpe.sku=10 or cpe.sku=20 and cpe.sku=25

i given u all possibility it will show u productcode,productname,and value

Comment: Can you give 1 example how to place this code in CMS Page? please